# Comparing values after searching entire binary tree

Tags: c, binary-tree

My binary tree is working perfectly. However, I am trying to compare a user input to the binary in order to check if they match. However, when I am checking the input, it is printing out "There is no student with that name" at every child of the btree.

Is there a way to make this print only once when i doesn't match and not print when it does match? [maybe i have to wait until the binary tree stops running, but i have no idea]

My project contains a text file containing the names of the students. I was wondering if there is a simpler way to search the file and compare it with the string entered by the user instead of searching in the btree.

> C:\Users\dd\c-eclipse-workspace\Code\src>database
>   namesids.txt marks.txt Enter command: FN Enter name to search:FREE
>   There is no student with that name.There is no student with that
>   name.There is no student with that name.There is no student with that
>   name.There is no student with that name.There is no student with that
>   name.There is no student with that name.There is no student with that
>   name.There is no student with that name.There is no student with that
>   name.There is no student with that name.There is no student with that
>   name.There is no student with that name.There is no student with that
>   name.There is no student with that name.There is no student with that
>   name.There is no student with that name.There is no student with that
>   name.There is no student with that name.There is no student with that
>   name.There is no student with that name.There is no student with that
>   name.There is no student with that name.There is no student with that
>   name.There is no student with that name.There is no student with that
>   name.There is no student with that name.There is no student with that
>   name.There is no student with that name.There is no student with that
>   name.There is no student with that name.There is no student with that
>   name.There is no student with that name.There is no student with that
>   name.There is no student with that name.There is no student with that
>   name.There is no student with that name.There is no student with that
>   name.There is no student with that name.There is no student with that
>   name.There is no student with that name.There is no student with that
>   name.There is no student with that name.There is no student with that
>   name.There is no student with that name.There is no student with that
>   name.There is no student with that name.There is no student with that
>   name.There is no student with that name.There is no student with that
>   name.

```
void searchTreeID(struct StudentRecord* root, int id){
    // if there is left tree traverse left
    //  printf("123");
    if(root->left != NULL){
        searchTreeID(root->left, id);
    }
    if(root->ID==id){
        // print the middle
        printf("Student Name%s",root->first);
        printf(" %-10s\n",root->last);
        printf("Student ID %10d\n",root->ID);
        printf("Total Grade %15d\n",root->marks);

    }   // if there is right tree traverse right
    else{
        printf("There is no student with that ID.\n");
    }
    if(root->right != NULL){

        searchTreeID(root->right,id);
    }
}
```

Comment: Do not post a picture of your code.  Post the code directly.

Comment: I fixed it thanks for the heads up!

Answer (score 4):

Your current code mixes two tasks (searching and printing) which should almost always be separated.

You should have one function called `search` that *returns* a StudentRecord or null.

You should have another function that prints an existing student record.

Then your main code will look like this:

```
StudentRecord *student = searchStudent(name);
if (student != NULL) {
    printStudent(student);
}
```

Comment: I new to C, coming from Java, and ive been starring at my code for the past 40mins. This is what i wrote so far. I know it is wrong but I know I have to pass the values somehow.

Comment: void search(struct StudentRecord* root, int id){
 int data;
 if(root->left != NULL){
   searchTreeID(root->left, id);
  }
  if(root->ID==id){
   ID(data);
  } // if there is right tree traverse right
  else{
   //printf("There is no student with that ID.\n");
  }
  if(root->right != NULL){

   searchTreeID(root->right,id);
  }
}


void ID(data){


if (data!=NULL){
 printf("123");
}
if(data ==NULL){
 printf("no id");
}

Comment: Oh, that's vital information that you know Java. In that case, go ahead and write your code in Java first. Then, when it's ready and tested, add a few `*`, and there you have your C code. And if that doesn't work, you can show is your Java code with the question "I tried to translate that to C", which is much easier to answer.